# Random number generator with range in Java

Tags: java, random

I have an array like:

```
byte[] a = new byte[4];

Random rnd;

    rnd.nextBytes(a);
```

I want to know if each element of this array named `a` in decimal is in range `0-255` or can be beyond this interval?

Comment: You might want to look at the definition of `byte`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html Min value can be `-2^7`. Please try to do a little bit of research by looking at JAVA Docs before posting the question.

Comment: A byte can only have 256 possible values, in Java the default range is -128 to 127 however with a mask `& 0xFF` you can make the range 0 to 255.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i wanted to know only f the number which is generated is -123 can i use this to my calculations of GF(256)

Comment: My masking it, you can make it an unsigned byte value.

Answer (score 3):

Java's [primitive byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is a data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.

That means the **minimum value is -128 (-2^7)** and the **maximum value is 127** (inclusive)(2^7 -1)

if you need or want a range between 0 and 255 you will need to correct the random number by yourself.

---

And btw, Random class must be initialized before you do something like:

```
rnd.nextBytes(a);
```